# Problems with character encoding in Rstudio

Tags: r, excel, character-encoding

I'm trying to import the following file into R studio 
[Eurostat NUTS NOMENCLATURE](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/345175/629341/NUTS+2010+-+NUTS+2013.xls)

When i import the file into excel the text is fine, however when i try this in R i get scrambled text for Belgium and Greek names e.g.

[image]

I've tried to import the file using the following library are using various encoding settings but with no success.

```
library("xlsx")
nuts_codes_all <-xlsx::read.xlsx("name of file", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: I would read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789330/r-on-windows-character-encoding-hell & this: http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Comment: thanks i'll give them a read

Answer (score 0):

Using the `readxl` package the characters look fine to me:

```
library(readxl)
data = read_xls("NUTS 2010 - NUTS 2013.xls",sheet = "NUTS2010-NUTS2013")
table(data$X__5)
```

[image: table_data]