# How to write CSV files so specific characters (accents, cyrillic) could be read properly?

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

I have a problem related to encoding.

Given a dataset like this

```
country     city
Ukraine     Kyiv правый
Costa Rica  San José
```

I'm converting it into csv this way:

```
write.csv(df, 'df.csv', fileEncoding = 'UTF-8', row.names = FALSE)
```

However, both when I'm exporting it to Google Sheets or when I'm reading it again in RStudio, it gives me the following output:

```
country    city
Ukraine    Kyiv <U+043F><U+0440><U+0430><U+0432><U+044B><U+0439>
Costa Rica San José
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I take it you're on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I use Windows

Comment: This is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789330/r-on-windows-character-encoding-hell) on Windows