# R Reading in files with symbols in Windows

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I'm having trouble reading in data from a file with unusual symbols; there is no error message but it stops once it hits a line with a specific symbol.

```
temp = read.csv(filePaths[i], header=TRUE, sep="\t", comment.char="#")
```

The last field which is read in is

```
Familial Non-VHL Clear Cell Renal Cancer;Birt-Hogg-Dub
```

Reading the file in Excel, this actually reads:

```
Familial Non-VHL Clear Cell Renal Cancer;Birt-Hogg-Dub-> Syndrome
```

but the "->" is a symbol; I believe this actually is "Birt–Hogg–Dubé syndrome", and the last character is probably being interpreted as an EOF char.

I only have this problem on Windows.

I've tried using different encoding (encoding = "UTF-8" and encoding = "bytes", fileEncoding = "UTF-8") without any difference.  I've looked at [Cannot read unicode .csv into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838613/cannot-read-unicode-csv-into-r) and searched but can't easily find an answer. Note that I probably can't use a specific language encoding. Thanks!

-- Update --
Created a file with one column, a header, 3 entries (problematic entry at #2), found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m2wak8rhyab6j2/test.txt?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the file (or the relevant part of it) to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: Just did, thanks for any help!

Comment: I see. `\032` is making problems. `download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m2wak8rhyab6j2/test.txt?dl=1", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"));library(stringi);read.csv(text=stri_read_lines(tf), header=T)` will load it.

Comment: I saw this answered here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/End-of-line-marker-td1577062.html

Answer (score 0):

As you've guessed, you need to change your file encoding when reading your file.

1. Determine what file encoding [you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows)
2. Use `read.table` specifying that file encoding via `fileEncoding`

Comment: Thanks, via the suggestion, I used Notepad and found that encoding was "ANSI".  When I tried fileEncoding = "ANSI" it gave "Unsupported conversion from 'ANSI' to ''.  Then I tried saving the file changing the encoding from "ANSI" to "UTF-8" but am still encountering errors while using fileEncoding="UTF-8"

Comment: When you opened it in Notepad, was it properly displayed?

Comment: Yes, it displayed all data (past the problematic character) if that is what you mean.