# What is causing R to give me this specific error message?

Tags: r

I have an R script running in RStudio. I am importing data (only 2 columns) from a csv file and doing some data wrangling for a ggplot2 session.

My R codes stand as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(magrittr)

agedata1 <- read.csv("myfile.csv", as.is=TRUE, header = TRUE)

Month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

mean_age <- agedata1 %>%
          filter(Mth %in% Month) %>%
          group_by(Mth) %>%
          summarize(xbar = round(mean(Age, na.rm = TRUE), 0))
```

When running the code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : object 'Age' not found
```

`agedata1` has only 2 columns: `Age` and `Mth`

(Age being 'int' and Mth being 'chr')

So why is it telling me that `Age` cannot be found?

updated info:

```
> str(agedata1)
'data.frame':   1114 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ï..Age: int  54 21 55 48 47 38 56 47 62 19 ...
 $ Mth   : chr  "Dec" "Dec" "Dec" "Dec" ...
```

There are some strange characters before the 'Age' header. I guess this is what is causing the issue! However, I checked the `csv` file and the header 'Age' looks good!

Comment: Could you provide the input data?

Comment: it works fine with : `agedata1 <- data.frame(Age = 1:10,Mth = sample(Month,10,replace = T))`

Comment: provide at least `str(agedata1)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I have added that information to my question

Comment: the name of the object is `i..Age` not `Age`.

Comment: @tushaR I understand your point but in the csv file it is simply 'Age'. Where could it go wrong during the import?

Comment: You can tweak your code to first rename the column `i..Age` to `Age` or tweak the logic to calculate the mean using  `mean(i..Age,na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: there could be some encoding issues though

Comment: try `data.table::fread("myfile.csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like importing the data changes the name of your variable. See [variable name is getting mangled, how do I prevent or repair this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802797/variable-name-is-getting-mangled-how-do-i-prevent-or-repair-this)

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. I am indeed facing the same issue.