# Import .csv file with Accent Characters in R

Tags: r

I cannot import the following cities:
Genève
Bülach
etc..

I have tried the solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. Do you have something that worked for you?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey ArbenK, welcome to the community. You need to provide us at least some code and the output. Furthermore, an example or the file would be perfect.

Comment: Please show us the R commands you're using to read the file.

Comment: Did you look at [Cannot read unicode .csv into R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16838613/4752675) ?

Comment: This might be an encoding problem. Maybe you could try to add `options(encoding = "utf-8")` in your .Rprofile file or you could make sure that the locale on your machine are set to utf-8

Answer (score 2):

Try importing your file specifying the encoding to `encoding = "UTF-8"` in the `read.csv` function.

For example, `data <- read.csv("your_file.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this other Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073636/cant-correctly-import-a-csv-with-italian-accented-characters-into-r) where the OP first tries to guess the encoding by using `guess_encoding("you file name here")` (from `readr` package). Then instead of writing `encoding= "[whatever it gives you]"` in your `read.csv` statement, try `fileEncoding = "[whatever it gives you]"`.

Incidentally for me, having "é" and "è", it gave me "ISO-8859-1" and I was able to import the data with the correct accented characters.