# Can't correctly import a CSV with Italian accented characters into R

Tags: r, csv, encoding, diacritics

I am quite a newbie to R and currently struggling with CSV importing. I am trying to import a large CSV table with accented characters in Italian (such as è,é,ì), but am failing to code it properly.

The command I first tried was:

```
comuni_giornaliero_dati_fino_31agosto <- read.csv("directory_here", header=FALSE, comment.char="#")
```

And what I got were messed up accents, e.g.

```
Agli<e8>
```

instead of "Agli**è**"

```
Mondov<ec>
```

instead of "Mondov**ì**" etc.

So I tried and guessed the encoding:

```
guess_encoding("directory_here",n_max=100,threshold = 0.2)
```

> A tibble: 1 x 2   encoding   confidence               1
> ISO-8859-1       0.47

So I tried specifying the encoding:

```
comuni_giornaliero_dati_fino_31agosto <- read.csv("directory_here", header=FALSE, comment.char="#",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

But I still can't have RStudio properly read accents. Any guesses? Feels like an easy task but I am too unfamiliar with R to sort this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just guessing, using `read.csv("directory_here", header=FALSE, comment.char="#",fileEncoding = "ISO-8859-1")` (i.e. `fileEncoding` instead of `encoding`) might work.  If not, please add the result of `sessionInfo()` to your post.

Comment: @user2554330 thank you, it solved the issue! Still struggling to grapple with the logic but it works.