# I can't read a file in polish special character folder name

Tags: r, xlsx

I' am trying to export folder names and read .xlsx files under the folder.
When i come across to polish folders due to special characters R cannot read it.
Any help?
Here is the example.
I can read the file in a normal folder name.

```
my_data1 <- read_excel("C:/data/Projects/Credit File conversion/Poland/Data_test/Credit upload file_Q42019 .xlsx")
> New names:
> * `` -> ...2
> * `` -> ...3
> * `` -> ...4
> * `` -> ...5
> * `` -> ...6
> * ... and 1 more problem
```

And when I try to read it under the folder SUWAŁA.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Polish")

my_data2 <- read_excel("C:/data/Projects/Credit File conversion/Poland/Data_test/SUWAŁA/Credit upload file_Q42019 .xlsx")
```

> Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'C:\data\Projects\Credit File conversion\Poland\Data_test\SUWAŁA\Credit upload file_Q42019 .xlsx' cannot be opened.

Comment: The Polish folder has special character encodings that you need to read in a certain way. This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461726/7120715

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Avoid spaces in the path. For my part `read.table("/tmp/SUWAŁA/test.csv")`  works fine with a `en_US` locale. Notice also that the error message is that the file cannot be opened, it does not say that it hasn't found the file.

Comment: @DJJ I cannot transform the xlsx files into csv before read it. I have a funtion that read 3 000 of  files in different polish folder names. transform the unstructered data there to structured data for modeling.

Comment: @bstrain it's not the special character encoding in the files that caused the problem. it's the folder name. this example of folder : SUWAŁA where the xlsx file was in.

Comment: My point was not about the xls but the path and folder names. I was showing that Polish special characters in the path works. I just don't use xls files in R. I'm afraid cannot help more than that given the information you provided. Start with a simple path like I did first. HTH